# Modal Popup Panel showing while refresh the webpage

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

In my web page I'm using a `ModalPopupExtender` to popup a modal popup windows to add an entry. The `PopupControlID` is a `panel`, which is resides in the same form. The issue is the while refreshing the webpage the `PopupControlID` panel showing for a short time and disappearing. The same issue happens while click on the `OK` button on the panel. Please see the Markup below, Please guide me to resolve the issue,

```
        <ATK:ModalPopupExtender
            BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"
            DropShadow="true"                                
            CancelControlID="btnCancel"                
            runat="server"
            PopupControlID="AddTopic"
            id="ModalPopupExtender1"                                                                          
            TargetControlID="btnAddNew"/> 


    <asp:Panel ID="AddTopic" runat="server"  CssClass="popup_Container"  Style="display: none;" >           
        <div class="popup_Titlebar" id="PopupHeader">
            <div class="TitlebarLeft">
                Add New Topic
            </div>
            <div class="TitlebarRight" onclick="cancel();">
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="popup_Body">    

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>                        
                <asp:Label ID="lblTopic" runat="server" Text="Topic Name"> </asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbTopicName" runat="server" Width="400px" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="tbTopicName"  >
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>               
            <br /> <br /> 
            <span style="padding-left:350px">
                <asp:Button ID="btnDone" runat="server" Text="Ok" onclick="btnDone_Click" /> 
                <input id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" type="button" OnClick="cancel();" />                      
            </span>
        </div>                   
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is the normal behaviour. If you want to show the popup after button click you have to set `ModalPopupExtender1.Show()` at the end of button click. But while refreshing modal popup will disappear.